# Does anyone know how headers like this are added in an email?

Tags: c#, email, header

Does anyone know how headers like this are added in an email?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlfD4.png)
Like the volaris and amazon emails, the header is updated actomatically.

Ty.

Comment: I can refer you to how google's Gmail handle this so that from a developer's perspective you get some understanding: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/getting-started

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. What exactly is your problem? What did you try and where are you stuck? In particular: where is your **code**? How should anyone here know what you´ve allready tried out yourself? How should we help you if we don´t know anything about your context? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So you are not talking about "email headers" but asking how that email was formatted into columns? That probably is an HTML formatted email. If you are curious, this are [email headers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/message-headers/message-headers.xhtml)

Comment: @Markuzy Thank you, it was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a html mail. With this solution you can create almost everthing on your mail.

You find a lot of solutions in the internet how you could create them. Just google it.

For example https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/html-email

Maybe you can save your mail as html and you see what they've done.

And like @Markuzy wrote in his comment. On top it would created by an email markup.